# Is there a way to ignore specific changelog md file on npm publish?

Tags: javascript, npm, package, package.json, changelog

I have an npm package where during ci/cd pipeline two changelog files are generated before the publish:
`CHANGELOG.md` and `CHANGELOG_INTERNAL.md`
First one goes to npm package normally, the second is meant for internal usage and shows some extra refactor and ci changes.
Npm docs say that

> The following paths and files are never ignored, so adding them to
> .npmignore is pointless:
>
> package.json, README (and its variants), CHANGELOG (and its variants),LICENSE / LICENCE

*Reference*: https://npm.github.io/publishing-pkgs-docs/publishing/the-npmignore-file.html

Question: Can I somehow make my `CHANGELOG_INTERNAL.md` not to go to package on publish (preferably using `package.json`)? And is there any logic for changelog file name that will prevent it from publishing? (cause *CHANGELOG (and its variants)* definition seems a bit vague)

**Update:** After some testing using `npm pack` command, I found that putting `CHANGELOG_INTERNAL.md` inside `.npmignore` helps to resolve the issue. Which is a bit weird taking into account the rule, where *CHANGELOG (and its variants)* are never ignored.

*Reference:* https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/using-npm/developers#keeping-files-out-of-your-package